# Adding matrices as cell element to a dataframe or an array or a list in R

Tags: arrays, r, list, matrix

I have multiple matrices of the configuration as m1=matrix(0,10,5), m2=matrix(0,10,5). I ideally wanted to add these matrices insides a new dataframe but struggling to define each element of df as a matrix. If that's not possible in R then I want to add these matrices as an array or list element. Please help me with an efficient way to achieve this using R. I would need to add these matrices inside a loop, but I know number of matrices so can pre-allocate memory. Also want to check, what if the matrices are not of same dimension ?

Answer (score 0):

We can place the matrix objects in a `list` and then do `Reduce` with `+`

```
Reduce(`+`, list(m1, m2))
```

If there are `NA` elements, it may be better to use `sum` as it has `na.rm` argument.  In that case, convert it to `array` and use `apply`

```
apply(array(c(m1, m2), c(10, 5, 2)), c(1, 2), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I have N (known) such matrices not just m1 & m2. These matrices have to added within a loop. I didn't follow how do you add the first matrix into the list, 2nd, 3rd and so on at the end of the list. I want to predefine list with enough memory to make it efficient and I know in advance how many matrices need to be added.

Comment: @mbansal  If you have N matrices with object names m1, m2, ...m100 etc.  then `Reduce('+', mget(paste0('m', 1:100)))`  All your questions cannot be answered in a single post